# In the morning prayer ראשית חכמה how do we translate the word בעזרתי?

Tags: tefilla

In the morning prayer ראשית חכמה how do we translate the word בעזרתי in the phrase א-ל שד-י בעזרתי?

The ב in בעזרתי does not seem to fit?

Comment: Could you please give a complete quote of all the words in the sentence?

Comment: א-ל שד-י בעזרתי

Comment: Did you look in an English siddur (for example, ArtScroll)?

Comment: Yes. No one translates the ב here as 'With'. Why not?